# Configure mysql-server instance

Tags: mysql

Version: Ubuntu  Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

How do I configure mysql-server? `dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server` only lets you change the password - nothing else.

I need to configure things like:

4. Choose Transactional Database Only to ensure that your MySQL database will use InnoDB as its default storage engine.
5. Set the InnoDB Tablespace settings to your requirements. (The default settings are acceptable.)
6. Set the approximate number of concurrent connections permitted to suit your Confluence usage requirements. You can use one of the presets or enter a number manually. Refer to the MySQL documentation for further information.
7. For the networking options, ensure the Enable TCP/IP Networking and Enable Strict Mode options are selected (default). Refer to the MySQL documentation on setting the networking and server SQL modes for further information.

Etc. How can I configure this?

EDIT: NB: These are examples, which I need to configure. But the question is meant to be general.

Comment: Have you actually tried to read MySQL's documentation? :) Anyway - you're looking pretty much for /etc/mysql/my.cnf file (just from memory right now, in case the location is different) I don't remember right now, but ubuntu may be using some extra configs included later in the main one. Anyway - you'll have to learn a bit about MySQL itself.

Comment: It looks like you're regurgitating some instructions from site. Provide context.

Comment: You can search Percona's website for the configuration generator, or edit the my.cnf directly.  Either way, running SQL requires effort, so once you get it going that's just the start of running it.

Comment: muru: Yes I am, and that's completely beside the point. My question is about how to configure ANYTHING, since dpkg-configure doesn't let you do that. The "regurgitating" is just and example of the things I need to configure.

Comment: Jacek: Thanks. However, the my.cnf file just points to the /conf.d/ directory. And all the files there are empty. I'm used to config files with some content, giving some hints about what/where to change things :-)

Comment: Well - what settings to use - it will strongly depend on what you're after.Personally for start I'd recommend using some defaults for a small or medium size db, and then basically start analyzing the config. It will start making sense for you, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the file `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`
And the documentation for [Server System Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html)

Comment: Thanks. It's /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf on my system, btw.

Comment: Also, that file cannot be edited, as anything inserted there will cause an "unknown variable" error when trying to log into the server (after restarting it). The correct file for parameters seems to be /etc/mysql/my.conf.